# Python understanding OOP, inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

I solve this problem:

Develop an application which operates with next types:

1. `Person` (field `Name`, method `ShowData()`)
2. `Student` (field `Education`)
3. `Worker` (field `WorkPlace`)

Classes `Student` and `Worker` are derived from class `Person`.

Class `Academy` in it's container collects `Students` and `Workers` and shows `Name`, `Education` or `WorkPlace` for all persons in method `ShowAll()`.

We can add new persons to `Academy` by calling method `AddPerson()`.

Which hierarchy of classes is the best 
for solving this problem?

Code should include inheritance and use collections.

This is my solution, but i don't know how to realize method `AddPerson`:

```
class Academy(object):
    theWholeList = []
    @staticmethod
    def showAll():
        for obj in Academy.theWholeList:
            if isinstance(obj,Student):
                print obj.name+' - '+obj.edu
            elif isinstance(obj,Worker):
                print obj.name+' - '+obj.wplace

class Person(Academy):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        super(Person, self).theWholeList.append(self)

    def showData(self):
        return vars(self)

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, edu):
        super(Student, self).__init__(name)
        self.edu = edu

class Worker(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, wplace):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(name)
        self.wplace = wplace
```

Maybe `Academy` must inherit `Person` and method `AddPerson` will be like that:

```
def add(self,name):
    super(Academy,self).__init__(name)
```

Comment: Looks like homework, but I'll say showAll should not be a staticmethod.

Comment: And this is fall again! Another batch of students struggling to get their homework done on SO ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing:

```
class Academy(object):
    theWholeList = []
    @staticmethod
    def showAll():
        for obj in Academy.theWholeList:
            if isinstance(obj,Student):
                print obj.name+' - '+obj.edu
            elif isinstance(obj,Worker):
                print obj.name+' - '+obj.wplace
```

you do not need to have `Academy`'s method `showAll()` be a static method, as on your design the Academy is legitimate to be a singleton, i.e. a class having a single instance.

Also `theWholeList` is a very bad name for a list. Because you *know* it is a list, as you're assigning it a list. The name shall describe its semantic, i.e. the kind of things it contains, what it is used for.

You should rewrite it as follows:

```
class Academy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person_list = []

    def show_all(self):
        for item in self.person_list:
            item.show_data()
```

And you would instanciate it once:

academy = Academy()

Then the following:

```
class Person(Academy):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        super(Person, self).theWholeList.append(self)
```

is bad design: in object oriented programming you should think about encapsulating data. Here you're making the assumption that `Person` knows the internals of `Academy`. And what if you decide to change `Academy`'s implementation so `theWholeList` is renamed? Or switched into a `dict()`? This should be transparent to the "user" of the class `Academy`. A better design should be:

```
class Academy:
    ... # cf earlier

    def add_person(self, person):
        self.person_list.append(person)

class Person(Academy):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def show_data(self):
        print("My name is: {}".format(name))
```

So you can use it as follows:

```
person_a = Person("John Doe")
person_b = Person("Jim Smith")
academy.add_person(person_a)
academy.add_person(person_b)
```

And finally you're wondering:

> Maybe Academy must inherit Person

Most of the time, subclassing is the wrong answer of a wrong question. You need to subclass when you want to *extend* or *specialize* behaviour of a class. A classical example would be:

```
class Animal:
    def noise(self):
        raise NotImplementedError # virtual method

class Duck(Animal):
    def noise(self):
        print("quack")

class Cat(Animal):
    def noise(self):
        print("meaw")
```

So in your case, you have a class person that implements show_data, and what you want is to extend the behaviour, for worker and student:

```
class Worker(Person): # a worker _is_ a person!
    def __init__(self, name, unit):
        # left as an exercise to the OP

    def show_data(self):
        # left as an exercise to the OP

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, promo):
        # left as an exercise to the OP

    def show_data(self):
        # left as an exercise to the OP
```

I won't get into much more details here, as I suppose you have a teacher you can ask more about the comments I made. But at least you tried, made some mistakes (AND MISTAKES ARE GOOD!). But I'm not giving you a full answer, my only goal here is to set you up in the right mind set to make your code a better design!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Btw having Worker and Student as subclasses of Person is also bad design; those are roles, not subtypes. In fact you can be easily both at once.

Comment: @peter I sooo much agree with you, but then we might need to tell the OP's teacher that his exercise is stupid :-) And not all teacher take such criticism in a good way (yes, I used to criticize my teacher's exercises when I was at uni)

Comment: Well being able to criticize is skill like any other. Saying "This is stupid design" to the teacher would be also stupid, but asking "Why do you think it should be done this way?" or "Could this be modeled this way instead?" changes the conversation a lot.

Comment: Also I am actually a student and a worker, so you can't even model me. :(

Comment: You can then make a diamond inheritance :-D (or how to import C++ OOP insanity in Python :-p)

Comment: Thanks for review and help :)  I have not had programming in the university. Just self learning) It is an example of the test task for admission to courses at the company.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to add people:

```
>>> academy = Academy()
>>> academy.add(Person('Pete'))
>>> academy.showAll()
Name: Pete

>>> academy.add(Student('Taras', 'Higher'))
>>> academy.showAll()
Name: Pete
Name: Taras, Education: Higher

>>> academy.add(Worker('riotburn', 'StackOverflow')
>>> academy.showAll()
Name: Pete
Name: Taras, Education: Higher
Name: riotburn, Workplace: StackOverflow
```

`showAll` needs to iterate over all people calling `ShowData` on them. This will be implemented differently for each type.

```
class Academy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []

    def add(self, person):
        self.people.append(person)

    def showAll(self):
        for person in self.people:
            person.ShowData()
```

Where for example, `Worker` will implement `ShowData` as:

```
def ShowData(self):
    print 'Name: ' + self.name + ', Education:' + self.edu
```